# mongod fails to start with error: mongod: symbol lookup error: mongod: undefined symbol: _ZN7pcrecpp2RE4InitEPKcPKNS_10RE_OptionsE

Tags: 12.04, mongodb

I am trying to start `mongod` but I get

```
$ mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
mongod: symbol lookup error: mongod: undefined symbol: _ZN7pcrecpp2RE4InitEPKcPKNS_10RE_OptionsE
```

Searching on google it seems to be related with `libpcre`; I tried to install last versions of `libpcre3` and `libpcre++` but it doesn't work.

MongoDB shell's version (and `mongodb-server`'s version) is 2.0.4. Ubuntu's version is 12.04. `libpcre3`'s version is 8.12-4. `libpcre++0`'s version is 0.9.5-5.1.

Thanks

Comment: You can also use the 10gen-provided repository and packages: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: If building from source, move/delete your build directory and do a clean build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issue, and we're not sure what caused it.

We tried to reinstall via `apt-get`, after purging and such, to no avail.

We downloaded the 64-bit precompiled version from the MongoDB website and tried running `mongod` from that package, and it started up fine. You'll probably want to stick with the 2.0.4 version - we used [this](http://downloads.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.4.tgz) file.

We moved the files in `bin/` to `/usr/bin`, and mongod was starting correctly again.

This isn't a nice fix, but it does work.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem recently on Amazon Linux, and the solution seems likely to be the same here as it was for me. The issue was that I was using the default operating system repositories (which had and have out-of-date versions of Mongo packages) instead of using 10gen's own repositories. 10gen's version of the package does not suffer from this bug.

After removing the Ubuntu repo version of MongoDB, here's how you can install up-to-date packages.

Import 10gen's gpg key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
```

Create a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list file and include the following line for the 10gen repository.

```
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list
```

Run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen`

Instructions were pulled from this page: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Anyone running into this issue on something in the RHEL family can find instructions here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/

Comment: To clarify: you had this issue on Amazon Linux (rpm-based), but are providing instructions for Ubuntu (deb-based), right? For those having this problem on Amazon Linux: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/ might help.